# Algorithm for diffing two deeply nested JavaScript objects that can identify insertions and moves by ID

Tags: javascript, algorithm, diff

I'm looking for pointers on how to approach diffing two nested objects with some semantic awareness. As an example, take an object that represents a company org chart. Each employee has some properties about them like their role and salary, as well as an "employees" array which contains any employees that report to them

```
const employees = [
{
    employee: 'John',
    employeeId: '1',
    roleDetails: {
      title: 'CEO',
      compensation: {
        bonus: 10000,
        salary: 899999
      }
    },
    employees: [
        {
            employee: 'Will',
            employeeId: '4',
            roleDetails: {
              title: 'Assistant to CEO',
              compensation: {
                bonus: 9919,
                salary: 17728
              }
            },
            employees: []
        },
        {
            employee: 'Jane',
            employeeId: '5',
            roleDetails: {
              title: 'Head of Operations',
              compensation: {
                bonus: 8190,
                salary: 17492
              }
            },
            employees: [
                {
                    employee: 'Tom',
                    employeeId: '6',
                    roleDetails: {
                      title: 'Operations Specialist',
                      compensation: {
                        bonus: 1839,
                        salary: 18429
                      }
                    },
                    employees: []
                },
                {
                    employee: 'Patricia',
                    employeeId: '7',
                    roleDetails: {
                      title: 'Operations Specialist',
                      compensation: {
                        bonus: 1378,
                        salary: 15890
                      }
                    },
                    employees: []
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
},
{
    employee: 'Ned',
    employeeId: '2',
    roleDetails: {
      title: 'CMO',
      compensation: {
        bonus: 18293,
        salary: 47291
      }
    },
    employees: [
        {
            employee: 'Trent',
            employeeId: '8',
            roleDetails: {
              title: 'Marketing Manager',
              compensation: {
                bonus: 10000,
                salary: 129999
              }
            },
            employees: [
                {
                    employee: 'Harry',
                    employeeId: '9',
                    roleDetails: {
                      title: 'Marketing Associate',
                      compensation: {
                        bonus: 18492,
                        salary: 188929
                      }
                    },
                    employees: []
                }

            ]
        }

    ]
},
{
    employee: 'Elsa',
    employeeId: '3',
    roleDetails: {
      title: 'CFO',
      compensation: {
        bonus: 10000,
        salary: 129999
      }
    },
    employees: [
        {
            employee: 'Harry',
            employeeId: '10',
            roleDetails: {
              title: 'Finance Associate',
              compensation: {
                bonus: 14829,
                salary: 1492002
              }
            },
            employees: []
        }
    ]
}]
```

Let's imagine we take a snapshot of this company once and then again 3 months later. In between there, some employees have been added or removed, some have had salary increases or job title changes, and some have changed roles so they now report to different people.

How would I create a diff that can accurately identify these changes to summarize to users in a human readable way? I tried a basic text diff like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cs5d3uwn/ but it doesn't recognize that two employees with the same ID are the same, and that ID never changes. So if one employee replaces the other at the same position, it reports that some of the attributes of that employee changed, not that it's a remove and add.

The ideal output would be something I could use to summarize the differences in words, like this:

```
changes: [ 
{ employeeId: 10, name: "Lisa", path: "employees[0].employees[2].employees[0]", change: 'ADDED' }
{ employeeId: 6, name: "Tom", path: "employees[0].employees[1].employees[0]", change: 'REMOVED' } 
{ employeeId: 4, name: "Ned", path: "employees[1]", change: 'UPDATED', key: 'salary', oldValue: 47291, newValue: 89399 },
{ employeeId: 7, name: "Harry", change: 'MOVED', oldPath: 'employees[1].employees[0].employees[0]', newPath: 'employees[1].employees[1]'}
{ employeeId: 7, name: "Harry", change: 'UPDATED', path: 'employees[1].employees[1].roleDetails.title', oldValue: 'Marketing Associate', newValue: 'Marketing Manager' }]
```

Any pointers on libraries to use or approaches to tackle the problem would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The nested structure can be flattened without any loss of information by giving each employee a `reportsTo` property. This contains as much information as the "lineage" that the OP suggests.

Since `reportsTo` has a simple scalar value (the id of the employee this employee reports to), it's change over time can be represented just like a change to any other employee prop.

Another advantage is concision in what constitutes a change.  If an employee's boss's boss's boss changes, that's a change in their lineage, but not really a change from an HR perspective (I would assert). That employee still reports to their same boss.

```js
let flatArray = [];

function transformEmployee(employee, reportsTo) {
  let result = Object.assign({}, employee);
  delete result.employees;
  result.reportsTo = reportsTo ? reportsTo.employeeId : null;
  flatArray.push(result);
}

// invoke fn on every employee in the tree, depth-first
function traverse(employee, reportsTo, fn) {
  if (employee.employeeId) fn(employee, reportsTo);
  employee.employees.forEach(e => traverse(e, employee, fn));
}

const employee = getData();
traverse(employee, null, transformEmployee)
console.log(flatArray)

function getData() {
  return {
    employees: [{
        employee: 'John',
        employeeId: '1',
        roleDetails: {
          title: 'CEO',
          compensation: {
            bonus: 10000,
            salary: 899999
          }
        },
        employees: [{
            employee: 'Will',
            employeeId: '4',
            roleDetails: {
              title: 'Assistant to CEO',
              compensation: {
                bonus: 9919,
                salary: 17728
              }
            },
            employees: []
          },
          {
            employee: 'Jane',
            employeeId: '5',
            roleDetails: {
              title: 'Head of Operations',
              compensation: {
                bonus: 8190,
                salary: 17492
              }
            },
            employees: [{
                employee: 'Tom',
                employeeId: '6',
                roleDetails: {
                  title: 'Operations Specialist',
                  compensation: {
                    bonus: 1839,
                    salary: 18429
                  }
                },
                employees: []
              },
              {
                employee: 'Patricia',
                employeeId: '7',
                roleDetails: {
                  title: 'Operations Specialist',
                  compensation: {
                    bonus: 1378,
                    salary: 15890
                  }
                },
                employees: []
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        employee: 'Ned',
        employeeId: '2',
        roleDetails: {
          title: 'CMO',
          compensation: {
            bonus: 18293,
            salary: 47291
          }
        },
        employees: [{
            employee: 'Trent',
            employeeId: '8',
            roleDetails: {
              title: 'Marketing Manager',
              compensation: {
                bonus: 10000,
                salary: 129999
              }
            },
            employees: [{
                employee: 'Harry',
                employeeId: '9',
                roleDetails: {
                  title: 'Marketing Associate',
                  compensation: {
                    bonus: 18492,
                    salary: 188929
                  }
                },
                employees: []
              }

            ]
          }

        ]
      },
      {
        employee: 'Elsa',
        employeeId: '3',
        roleDetails: {
          title: 'CFO',
          compensation: {
            bonus: 10000,
            salary: 129999
          }
        },
        employees: [{
          employee: 'Harry',
          employeeId: '10',
          roleDetails: {
            title: 'Finance Associate',
            compensation: {
              bonus: 14829,
              salary: 1492002
            }
          },
          employees: []
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With that, we're ready to record differences between two arrays. We can produce three arrays: `adds`, `drops`, and `diffs`

adds and drops are straight-forward enough...

```
const oldEmployees = [ /* ... */];
const newEmployees = [ /* ... */];

// adds are employees in the new array not in the old array
const adds = newEmployees.filter(newE =>
  !oldEmployees.find(oldE => oldE.employeeId === newE.employeeId));

// drops are employees in the old array not in the new array
const drops = oldEmployees.filter(newE =>
  !newEmployees.find(oldE => oldE.employeeId === newE.employeeId));
```

That leaves `diffs`, which are employees (matched by ids) in both arrays but have had one or more value change.  Here's a working demonstration of how to compare two objects with a fixed set of keys that are known a priori...

```js
// compare two versions of an employee (with the same ids)
// create a diff object that describes differences
// this presumes a fixed set of keys, as the OP has
function compare(id, newE, oldE, diffs) {
  const keyPaths = [['employee'], ['reportsTo'], ['roleDetails', 'title'], ['roleDetails', 'compensation', 'salary'], ['roleDetails', 'compensation', 'bonus']];
  keyPaths.forEach(key => {
    let newValue = valueAtPath(newE, key);
    let oldValue = valueAtPath(oldE, key);
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      diffs.push({ id, key: key.join('.'), oldValue, newValue });
    }
  });
}

// get a value at a path in an object
function valueAtPath(object, path) {
  if (path.length === 1) return object[path[0]];
  return valueAtPath(object[path[0]], path.slice(1))
}

let oldElsa = {
  employee: 'Elsa',
  employeeId: '3',
  reportsTo: '12',
  roleDetails: {
    title: 'Bookkeepper',
    compensation: {
      bonus: 1000,
      salary: 60000
    }
  }
}

let newElsa = {
  employee: 'Elsa',
  employeeId: '3',
  reportsTo: '2',
  roleDetails: {
    title: 'CFO',
    compensation: {
      bonus: 10000,
      salary: 129999
    }
  }
}

let diffs = []
compare(3, newElsa, oldElsa, diffs);
console.log(diffs)
```

Given our old and new employee sets, we'd just run this diff process on all of them...

```
const oldEmployees = [ /* ... */];
const newEmployees = [ /* ... */];
let diffs = [];

newEmployees.forEach(newE => {
  const id = newE.employeeId;
  const oldE = oldEmployees.find(o => o.employeeId === id));
  compare(id, newE, oldE, diffs);
});
```